# Why do I get an array of chars when splitting a string using \d* regex notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, my string is:

```
 "this8is8my8string"
```

And here are the two varied results:

```
2.1.0 :084 > str.split(%r{\d})
 => ["this", "is", "my", "string"] 
2.1.0 :085 > str.split(%r{\d*})
 => ["t", "h", "i", "s", "i", "s", "m", "y", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

I don't quite understand why the string is being split by characters if there is no digits in between them. Could somebody clarify what is going on in the second version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `*` means "zero or more," and:

```
"this8is8my8string"
 ^^ there's 0 or more digits between the t and the h
  ^^ there's 0 or more digits between the h and the i
   ^^ there's 0 or more digits between the i and the s
    ^^ well... you get the point
```

You're probably looking for `+`. `\d+` would mean "one or more digits."

Also, on a slightly related topic: typically regexen in Ruby are seen as regex literals, like `/\d*/`, not with the `%r` format. That actually threw me off a little when I read your question; it seems very strange. I suggest using the `/.../` literal format to make your code easier to read for most Rubyists.